# XSLT 2.0: Get elements where attributes are distinct

Tags: xml, xslt, unique, distinct-values

I have an XML format as follows:

```
<Items>
  <Item id="1">
  </Item>
  <Item id="2">
  </Item>
  <Item id="1">
  </Item>
  <Item id="3">
  </Item>
</Items>
```

I am trying to declare an XSLT 2.0 variable that will contain all  elements where "id" is unique. If the "id" is NOT unique, only the first instance should be output, such that the variable will store:

```
<Item id="1">
</Item>
<Item id="2">
</Item>
<Item id="3">
</Item>
```

The following code will give me all of the unique @id attributes, but NOT their parent (Item):

```
<xsl:variable name="uniqueItems" select="distinct-values(/Items/Item/@id)"/>
```

I want to do somelike this:

```
<xsl:variable name="uniqueItems" select="distinct-values(/Items/Item/@id)/parent::node()"/>
```

But this is obviously not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
<xsl:key name="id" match="Item" use="@id"/>
```

you could use `<xsl:variable name="uniqueItems" select="/Items/Item[not(key('id', @id)[2])]"/>`.

Or use `for-each-group` to find groups of single items:

```
<xsl:variable name="uniqueItems" as="element(Item)">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="/Items/Item" group-by="@id">
   <xsl:if test="not(current-group()[2])">
    <xsl:sequence select="."/>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>
```

If you want to eliminate duplicates then with

```
<xsl:variable name="uniqueItems" as="element(Item)">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="/Items/Item" group-by="@id">
   <xsl:sequence select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  

I apologise for perhaps lacking precision in my original question.  

What I want is to incude the *first* occurrence of anything which has a duplicate ID.  

I'm essentially trying to ignore duplicate values of @id.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The for-each-group structure suited my needs perfectly.